# Electric circuits in TeX, LaTeX, and Friends

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

What are some ways to draw electric circuits in TeX systems?

I'm making this community wiki since I haven't found a question related to this.

I was thinking along the lines of [circuitikz](http://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz). What do you think of that? Other examples are more than welcome, of course.

Comment: I'd be interested to see examples comparing the different approaches, as well.

Comment: Well after a look into the manuals, Circuitikz is the most complete package in term of components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From version 2.10 on, TikZ has a `circuits` library. It seems to be based on CircuiTikz.

Comment: For those interested, [this is an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library) that uses TikZ `circuits.ee.IEC` library.

Comment: You can also find more information at the [PGF manual here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (warning: the full manual has more than 1100 pages).

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend **circuit macros** (https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/).

It is not a LaTeX plugin as **circuitikz**. The circuit drawing makes use of *m4* (macro language) and *dpic* (PIC drawing language) to reach a LaTeX drawing file (e.g. tikz pgf commands actually).

The extra steps gives a lot of power and flexibility. And indeed the circuit symbols in Dwight Aplevich's M4 **circuit macros** look more pleasing. (https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html)

Comment: The biggest disadvantage is the multi-step processing.
Besides than that it looks interesting and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: The symbols look cool and the diagrams are beautiful, but the syntax is unintuitive. To place an element, you have to write something like `{R18: resistor(up_ elen_*1.2); llabel(,R_{18}) }` where 1.2 is the vertical shift from the current point (I think).

Comment: Access [here](http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and look for Examples and Advanced Examples for a big feature of circuit_macros. There are some souces and some tips.

Answer (score 6):

For users of Asymptote, there seems to be a new package for doing this, discussed [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/forums/forum/409349/topic/3867701).

Comment: Thanks Will. I've been using Asymptote for a year now and really love it. Although I almost never use it inside of LateX. I generate the image in its own file and import it. Up to now I've been drawing my own circuit elements with it.

Answer (score 5):

Since somebody has to do it, it might as well be me. How about [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-circuit-schematics-symbols/) or [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/logic-circuits-library/)?

Comment: Considering that the examples do a `\usepackage{...}`, are these documented in `texdoc pgfmanual`?

Comment: @Kit: I'm not sure. Take a look in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen two Metapost-based circuit drawing environments:

1. Tomasz Cholewo's [mpcirc](http://ci.louisville.edu/tom/software/LaTeX/mpcirc/), which is a suite of four minimally documented Metapost libraries to support writing Metapost to layout circuits.  The examples are impressively compact, but I don't understand the code;
2. Gustavo Argañaraz' [makecirc](ftp://cam.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/makecirc/), which is a pair of Metapost libraries, to handle circuit layout and creating Latex labels.  The code is much more what one would expect, and there is a user guide.

Makecirc is somewhat tied to Latex, because its label creation library uses latex-specific code to create parametric label ranges.  Mpcirc should work with Context.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [cirkuit](http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html). This kde editor for tikZ [circuit macros](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/) provides live preview, snippets and more.

[image: cirkuit]

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to have a look the [pst-circ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/) package from the pstricks family.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be to actually use a normal cad program, and then export into a format that could be used by LaTeX (and friends). Preferable a format like svg (scalable vector graphics) so that you could zoom in the resulting pdf.

I checked over at chiphacker for cad programs:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/what-are-the-best-free-schematic-tools-out-there
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/what-are-low-cost-circuit-and-pcb-design-software/1226#1226

And maybe [kicad](http://www.lis.inpg.fr/realise_au_lis/kicad/) can be useful since that seem to have svn export, but I have not tried it my self.

Comment: The usual reasons for wanting to do figures from a tex-aware programme apply. 1) You want the fonts and line-weights of the labels to match with the body text; 2) You want to be able to use tex mathmode facilities for the labelling; 3) You want to be able to use macros for the labels so you can redefine your notation for the whole document with a single change to a `\newcommand`. A normal CAD programme + export to eps + psfrag may work, but is generally more work than you would like, due to fine-tuning positioning of labels.