# Creating custom electronic components in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circuitikz

In Tikz there is an opportunity to draw logical gates,... I was wondering if it is possible (and easy) to make custom components, like a CMOS-transistor, a Multiplexer, flip-flop,... Perhaps these components also exists. However I was wondering how it is possible to make them myself.

Additionally I have noticed you can of course define anchor points to these components. Like (AND.input 1). How are these anchors defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [D-FlipFlop](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/) example in [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

You can find some more references about drawing circuits in [A good tool to make electronic schematics and export them vectorially?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/a-good-tool-to-make-electronic-schematics-and-export-them-vectorially)

Comment: The D-FlipFlop example made a lot of things clear. Thnx!