# Drawing a multiplexer with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a logical circuit with a multiplexer. Is there any symbol provided by the TikZ package? I'm using the TikZ library `circuits.logic` to draw logical circuit symbols.

Or is there any possibility to built a multiplexer by myself and provide the number of inputs I need (so I can connect them to other logical symbols)?

Comment: Perhaps show us a hand-drawn picture of your multiplexer.

Comment: In terms of creating it yourself (with inputs (which would be anchors in TikZ)) you can have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/creating-node-shapes. If this is the road you wish to go down and have additional questions, you can ask more specific/directed ones.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [circuitikz](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/) package? I think it exceeds the possibilities of `circuits.logic`. The [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) has got a section entitled “5.1.1 Logic Ports”, which might help you.

Or do you rather want it to be just a box with some inputs and outputs as depicted in the following image?

[image: Prime gate with triple multiplexer.]

Prime gate with triple multiplexer.
Image source: By MovGP0 at de.wikipedia.org, Licensed under CC-BY-SA-2.0-DE.

Comment: Yes I tried the circuitikz package. But I use tikz to have more flexibility to create logical circuits. The graphic you posted is exactly what I want. I want to use labels for the inputs and connect the inputs and outputs to other logical symbols.

Comment: In [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14690/8432) I found a reference to [a TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/), which you could possibly change to meet your needs. By the way, it is by [Martin Scharrer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer), so maybe he has more insight on how to achieve this.