# AC source symbol in TikZ circuits.ee.IEC library

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, circuitikz

I can draw an AC source manually:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
  \draw (2,0) circle (2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How do I declare an `ACsource` symbol so that I can just write the following, or something similar and more correct:

```
\draw (0,5) to [ACsource={volt=220}] (5,5);
```

Also, when I am able to declare it as a symbol, will it already behave the same way as the other default symbols in the `circuits` library? To illustrate, will it behave like this `resistor`, drawing connector lines and labels in the appropriate places? I also want the `ACsource` to be the proper size that obeys keys like `small circuit symbols`, `huge circuit symbols`, etc.

```
\draw (0,0) to [resistor={ohm=5}] (5,0);
```

---

**In response to @morbusg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library/7495#7495):**

I'm using LaTeX. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac current source}
\tikzset{%
          ac current source IEC graphic/.style={%
            circuit symbol lines,
            circuit symbol size = width 2 height 2,
            shape = generic circle IEC,
            /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={%
              \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}}
              \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
              \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
              \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
              \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
              \pgfusepath{stroke}
            },
            transform shape
          }
}
\tikzset{%
          circuit ee IEC/.append style={%
            {set ac current source graphic = ac current source IEC graphic}
          }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw node [ac current source, info=230V] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile that, I'd get the following error:

> Package `pgfkeys` Error: I do not know the key `'/tikz/set ac current source graphic = ac current source IEC graphic'` and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

@morbusg's solution works perfectly with Plain TeX, but I'm using LaTeX. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that perfectly suits my requirements.
[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac source}
\tikzset{set ac source graphic = ac source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
         ac source IEC graphic/.style=
          {
           transform shape,
           circuit symbol lines,
           circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
           shape=generic circle IEC,
           /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background=
            {
             \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
             \pgfusepathqstroke
            }
          }
        }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,0)    to [ac source={info={110V 60Hz},near start},resistor={near end}] (3,0);
    \draw (0,-1.5) to [ac source={volt=220,near start}, inductor={near end}]        (3,-1.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This first one is a Plain-TeX version which has some extra definitions for "including" the ac source graphic as a toggleable (IEC/US/etc.) shape for circuits.ee. This is not necessary; see further below for a stripped-down LaTeX-version.

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac current source}
\tikzset{ac current source IEC graphic/.style={
    circuit symbol lines,
    circuit symbol size=width 2 height 2,
    shape=generic circle IEC,
    /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}} 
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}} 
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}} 
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}} 
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}} 
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    },
    transform shape
  }
}
\tikzset{circuit ee IEC/.append style=
  {set ac current source graphic = ac current source IEC graphic}
}

\tikzpicture[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw node[ac current source, huge circuit symbols,info=230V] {};
  \draw (1,0) node[ac current source, small circuit symbols,info=230V] {};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

**EDIT:** LaTeX (without the extra definitions):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{ac source/.style={
  circuit symbol lines,
  circuit symbol size = width 2 height 2,
  shape = generic circle IEC,
  /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  },
  transform shape
}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,small circuit symbols]
    \node[ac source,volt=230] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, there's a small (insignificant) typo, so just `s/ac current source/ac source/g` if you will.

Comment: +1 Works perfectly with Plain TeX, but I'm using LaTeX. See my edits on my question.

Comment: You can just edit your answer.

Comment: Your answers provided important insights. I eventually found a solution that's suited to my needs. See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library/7898#7898) below.