# How do I contribute to TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, contribute

Stemming from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7438/791) and with due credits to [@morbusg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library/7495#7495), I was able to create a very fundamental symbol for the `circuits.ee.IEC` TikZ library, the AC voltage source. I call it the `ac source`. The code for it is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library/7898#7898).
[image]

I'd like it to be added to the abovementioned TikZ library, but I don't know how. I don't have a SourceForge account. I'm not familiar with SVN, or any source control system for that matter. My idea is to contact Till Tantau or Mark Wibrow so that they can refactor it to their coding style, but I don't see their e-mail addresses in the `pgfmanual`. Any ideas?

Comment: TikZ still uses CVS (!), so that doesn't work, but with more modern version control systems, I think it is usual to create a branch with your changes and then propose that for merging (eg. via the bug-tracker). So you should probably just append a patch file to the Patches bugtracker on pgf's sourceforge page, as Joseph said.

Comment: @Caramdir, thanks for the tip about CVS. I forgot to mention that I'm not familiar with any source control system - SVN, CVS, Mercurial or otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

For a one-off addition, I think you'd be best adding this as a feature request to the tracker on SourceForge. As a package developer myself, I find it a lot easier to have things listed in the database so I don't forget about them, which does happen with e-mails. That does mean having an account on SourceForge: you can use [OpenID](http://openid.net/), which should mean you can use an existing account somewhere as a log in (for example, I log in both here and at SourceForge using an OpenID from [MyOpenID](https://www.myopenid.com/)).

Answer (score 4):

You can also join the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=pgf-users) and send it there.

Comment: How do I "send" to the mailing list? I was expecting something like a forum where I can "Add a New Thread", but I think it's different. Shall I send an e-mail to `pgf-users@sourceforge.net`? And how do I get a heads-up in my inbox if a reply comes in? (This ought to be a question for another SE site. I'm such a noob when it comes to mailing lists. On the Internet, I grew up on forums, Facebook, and StackExchange :))

Comment: “On the Internet I grew up on Facebook” -- you make me feel old. For most mailing lists, you should subscribe first (in this case at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pgf-users). This way you will get all the mail on the list, so you might want to create some mail filter. If you don't subscribe, the list might ignore your mails, or you might not get all replies (as people ofter reply only to the list and don't cc you personally).

Comment: @Caramdir: And I thought StackExchange would be highlighted `:)` How did you navigate to that link? I didn't find that anywhere on the page given by @Matthew. I mean, was it by experience that you know you _should_ manually browse to the `lists.sourceforge.net` domain?

Comment: Oh, there you go. It's in the ["Mailing Lists" page](https://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=142562), not the "pgf-users" page

Comment: @Kit: sf.net is rather hard to navigate...