# Change appearance of voltage source in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I prefer my voltage sources as in the image below. How can I achieve this in circuitikz?

There is an identical question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33163/tikz-with-circuit-libs-change-appearance-of-voltage-source), however for plain tikz. I tried to implement the solution given their, but it does not seem to work in combination with circtuitikz. In fact it generates an error.

[image]

Comment: Cisrcuitikz IS a tikzpicture.  You can use the same solution, only easier with node[ocirc] or \to[short,-o].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach is to use `open` with `o-o` option:

```
\draw (0,0) to ++(1,0) to[open,o-o,l={$U_\sim$}] ++(1,0) to ++(1,0);
```

Or else, custom component `customV` can be defined and used:

```
\draw (3.5,0) to[customV,l={$U_\sim$}] ++(3,0);
```

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{customV}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsource/width}}{
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
}
  \def\pgf@circ@customV@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{customV}{#1}}
  \compattikzset{customV/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@customV@path, label=#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to ++(1,0) to[open,o-o,l={$U_\sim$}] ++(1,0) to ++(1,0);
\draw (3.5,0) to[customV,l={$U_\sim$}] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works very well. Is it possible to add "+" / "-" for dc current sources?

Comment: @user1583209 didn't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to add the polarity, i.e. a plus and a minus sign below or above the small circles of the voltage source.

Comment: @user1583209 replacing `l={$U_\sim$}` with `v={$U_\sim$}` will result in +/- symbols on either sides. See if that is fine for you.

Comment: The `v={$U_\sim$}' creates a round arrow for me, not +/- symbols.

Comment: @user1583209 +/- comes in american style. use `to[american,customV,v={$U_\sim$}]` or `to[american,open,o-o,v={$U_\sim$}]`