# Define a new Source Object in CircuiTikZ

Tags: circuitikz

German school books use open circles to mark electrical sources:

```
 \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 
 \makeatletter
 \pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{customV}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsource/width}}{
     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
     \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
     \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
 }
 \def\pgf@circ@customV@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{customV}{#1}}
 \compattikzset{customV/.style={\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@customV@path, label=#1}}
 \makeatother
 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[customV] ++(3,0);
 \end{circuitikz}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

This solution I found at [Change appearance of voltage source in circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481435/change-appearance-of-voltage-source-in-circuitikz) But to be honest, I don't get how the costumV works.

So I would like to ask for two things I additionally need:

1. In case of direct current, + and - where added above the circles, alternate current through a ~ in the middle top the two circles.
2. How to control the distance between the circles?

Thanks a lot for any hint :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new infrastructure of `circuitikz` you can define your symbol, for example, like this (I borrowed part of [Jasper Habicht's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683795/38080)); that way the new bipole is recognized as a voltage source, and it scales (or changes style) correctly.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
% use a separate width and height. Notice that the height
% will basically decide at which distance the labels are
% drawn.
\ctikzset{bipoles/germanDCV/height/.initial=.20}
\ctikzset{bipoles/germanDCV/width/.initial=.60}
% put the bipole in the "sources" class, so that it will scale
% with them
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{sources}
{
    % save the name of this node so that we can reference the
    % internal nodes
    \savedmacro{\thisshape}{\def\thisshape{\tikz@fig@name}}
}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanDCV/height}}
{germanDCV}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanDCV/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanDCV/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{\thisshape-L}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    % use the ocirc anchor to position the sign, so it will do the right thing
    % if you change "ocirc" dimensions.
    \pgftext[bottom, at=\pgfpointanchor{\thisshape-L}{n}]{\footnotesize $\mathstrut +$}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{\thisshape-R}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftext[bottom, at=\pgfpointanchor{\thisshape-R}{n}]{\footnotesize $\mathstrut -$}
}
% activate the bipole, specifying that it's a voltage, and that the voltage
% symbols are inside and drawn with the symbol. That will work correctly only with
% "american" settings. You can try with european too, in that case use true for the
% is voltageoutsideofsymbol and adjust the height so that the arrow will not overlap.
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple@opt{v}{germanDCV}{\circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true,
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=false}
%%%%
%%%% and this is the AC version...
\ctikzset{bipoles/germanACV/height/.initial=.20}
\ctikzset{bipoles/germanACV/width/.initial=.60}
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{sources}
{
    % save the name of this node so that we can reference the
    % internal nodes
    \savedmacro{\thisshape}{\def\thisshape{\tikz@fig@name}}
}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanACV/height}}
{germanACV}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanACV/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/germanACV/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    % play with the coordinate here to move the symbol...
    \pgftext[bottom, at=\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}]{\small ${\sim}$}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{\thisshape-L}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{\thisshape-R}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
}
% activate the bipole, specifying that it's a voltage, and that the voltage
% symbols are inside and drawn with the symbol. That will work correctly only with
% "american" settings. You can try with european too, in that case use true for the
% is voltageoutsideofsymbol and adjust the height so that the arrow will not overlap.
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple@opt{v}{germanACV}{\circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true,
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,1) to[germanDCV, name=N1] ++(2,0) to[germanDCV, mirror, invert] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,0) to[american, germanDCV=\SI{3}{V}] ++(2,0)
        to[germanDCV, l_=$V_2$, mirror, invert, name=N2] ++(2,0);
    \draw [thin, red] (N1-R) -- (N2-R); % N2 is inverted
    \draw [color=blue] (0,-1)  to[germanACV, name=N1] ++(2,0)
        to[germanACV, l_=$V_3$] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think it should be easy to generate the AC one, but I'll add it if requested.

Comment: Thank you, that's it!

It would be nice if you could also add the AC one :)

Comment: @Bigga done (I had not time earlier, sorry...)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late answer, didn't  recognize your comment

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could actually just use the following code (which is only a slight modification of an example from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[american voltages] 
    (0,1.5) -- ++(0.5,0) to[open, v=$\sim$, o-o] ++(2,0) -- ++(0.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But if you want to stick to the custom code you found, you could add the current signs as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{customV}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsource/width}}{
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@left}{7pt}}
    \pgfnode{rectangle}{center}{\footnotesize $+$}{}{}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{rectangle}{center}{\footnotesize $-$}{}{}
}
  \def\pgf@circ@customV@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{customV}{#1}}
  \compattikzset{customV/.style={\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@customV@path, label=#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[customV] ++(3,0);

\draw (0,-1) to[customV={$\sim$}] ++(3,0);

\draw (0,-2) to[customV={$\sim$}, invert] ++(3,0);

\draw (0,-3) to[customV={$\sim$}, bipoles/vsource/width=1] ++(3,0);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note, that (as pointed out in the comments to the original answer already) you can get current signs also using the `v` option in combination with the `american voltages` option, but they would not sit on top of the small circles:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{customV}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/open/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsource/width}}{
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
}
  \def\pgf@circ@customV@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{customV}{#1}}
  \compattikzset{customV/.style={\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@customV@path, label=#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]

\draw (0,-1) to[customV, v^={$\sim$}] ++(3,0);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, you can use the option `american voltages` either on the whole `tikzpicture` environment, on single `\draw` macros or you can use the `american` option on `to`-paths, such as:

```
\draw (0,-1) to[american, customV, v^={$\sim$}] ++(3,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and your description :)