# Fixing a circuit diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

Making some electric circuits in tikz for the very first time, and need to 
replicate the following image

[image]

Not a very complicated circuit. Now here is what I have done so far

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac source}
\tikzset{set ac source graphic = ac source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
         ac source IEC graphic/.style=
          {
           transform shape,
           circuit symbol lines,
           circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
           shape=generic circle IEC,
           /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background=
            {
             \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8pt}{0pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{-0.4pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}
             \pgfusepathqstroke
            }
          }
        }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [capacitor={info={$q$\ \ $-q$}}]     ++(1, 0)
              to [resistor={info ={$R$}}]             ++(2, 0) 
              to [current direction' = {info = {$I$}}]++(0,-2) 
              to [inductor={info=$L$}]                  (0,-2)  
              to [ac source={info={$V$}}]               (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea what I have done so far, I just randomly copied examples from the internet. The nodes is a mess, as I just kept trying until they all connected.
What does the ++ mean? And could someone help me understand how to fix my circuit diagram to resemble the image above? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution leads to:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac source}
\tikzset{set ac source graphic = ac source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
         ac source IEC graphic/.style=
          {
           transform shape,
           circuit symbol lines,
           circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
           shape=generic circle IEC,
           /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background=
            {
             \pgftransformrotate{90}
             \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.575pt}{0pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.3pt}{0.3pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.3pt}{-0.3pt}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.3pt}{-0.3pt}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.3pt}{0.3pt}}
             \pgfusepathqstroke
            }
          }
        }
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1.5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [capacitor={info'={$C$}}]     ++(1.5, 0)
              to [resistor={info'={$R$}}]             ++(2.5, 0) 
              to [current direction = {info' = {$I$}}]++(0,-3) 
              to [inductor={info'=$L$}]                  (0,-3)  
              to [ac source={info={$V$}}]               (0,0);

\node[above right] at (0.75,0){$-q$};        
\node[above left] at (0.75,0){$q$ \ };   
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

From the starting point `(0,0)`, all elements are displayed in sequence. For example, the capacitor is placed from the starting point until coordinate `(1.5,0)` (that's the meaning behind ++). It is possible to display information with the key `info` or `info'`; in general the `'` allows you to invert the positioning of a label or the direction of the current: that's why in my example I used just `current direction` to let the arrow point down.

For what concern the labels `q` and `-q` rather than insert them with the key `info` I preferred to used simple nodes: from one hand this allows to introduce `C` with `info` and from the other hand allows a better positioning of `q` and `-q`.

At last, to rotate the symbol of the voltage source I simply add to your code `\pgftransformrotate{90}` and I reduced a bit the size.

Comment: `++` is used to add the following coordinate to the last used coordinate. In this example, it is equal to the sequence `(0,0)--(1.5,0)--(4,0)--(4-3)--(0,-3)--(0,0)`.

Comment: Yes: reading again what I wrote seem also to me a bit obscure `:P`; your comment clarifies what I had in mind.

Comment: No problem, that's meant for the general audience.

Answer (score 2):

@ClaudioFiandrino beat me to answer the question about `++` `:)`, but I have some other improvements/remarks to make. See the modified code below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ac source}
\tikzset{set ac source graphic = ac source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
         ac source IEC graphic/.style=
          {
           transform shape,
           circuit symbol lines,
           circuit symbol size = width 3 height 3,
           shape=generic circle IEC,
           /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background=
            {
             \pgftransformresetnontranslations
             \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.8\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{-0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
             \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{-0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
             \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0.4\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
             \pgfusepathqstroke
            }
          }
        }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [capacitor={info={$q$\ \ $-q$}}]     ++(1, 0)
              to [resistor={info ={$R$}}]             ++(2, 0) 
              to [current direction = {info = {$I$}}]++(0,-2) 
              to [inductor={info=$L$}]                  (0,-2)  
              to [ac source={info={$V$}}]               (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which has this as output:

[image]

First, it is a good idea to use `\tikzcircuitssizeunit` as unit, then the figure always scales correctly.

Second, `\pgftransformresetnontranslations` is also more general than having an explicit specification for a rotation of 90 degrees and makes the graphic reusable for any angle without extra effort.

Last, about the AC source, I'd like to point to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/rotationally-correct-ac-source-symbol-in-tikz) (credit goes to @Jake for his great answer) posted by me (the very first I ever posted here on `TeX.SE`... ahhh - nostalgia... `:)`).

Comment: Oh: I wasn't aware of `\pgftransformresetnontranslations`! +1 for this `:)`