# A less hacky way of drawing 2-bus single line diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, draw, circuits

I recently started using TikZ and want to replicate a simple 2-bus single line diagram as follows (with the transformer drawn on Paint... and highlighted in yellow, plus some changes in the annotation) using the CircuiTikZ package
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary[shapes,arrows.meta]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\renewcommand{\j}{\mathbf{j}}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol=source,
    set source graphic={
        draw,
        circuit symbol lines,
        circuit symbol size=width 2.5 height 2.5,
        shape=generic circle IEC,
        transform shape,
        thick,
        },
    ac/.style={
        /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
            \pgftransformresetnontranslations
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.75\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0pt}}
            \pgfpathsine{
                \pgfpoint{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
            }
            \pgfpathcosine{
                \pgfpoint{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{-0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
            }
            \pgfpathsine{
                \pgfpoint{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{-0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
            }
            \pgfpathcosine{
                \pgfpoint{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0.375\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
            }
            \pgfusepathqstroke
        }
    },
    admittance/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        minimum width=10mm,
        minimum height=3mm,
        semithick
    },
    point/.style={
        coordinate
    },
    arrow/.style={
        ->,shorten >=0pt,
        >={Stealth[round]},
        semithick
    },
    line/.style={
        semithick
    }
}

\begin{circuitikz}  
% components
\node at (0,0) [source=ac] (v1) {};
\node at (2.5,0) [oosourcetransshape] (xformer1) {};
\node at (2.5,-0.5) {$\tau = t e^{\theta_{\text{s}}}$};
\node at (5,0) [admittance] (y1) {}; 
\node at (5,-0.5) {$y = g - \j b$};
\node at (7.75,0) [point] (load1) {};

% draw bus bars
\node at (1,0) [point] (bus1) {};
\node at (7,0) [point] (bus2) {};
\node at (1,0.75) {$\upsilon_1 = 1\angle0$};
\node at (7,0.75) {$\upsilon_2 = V_2 \angle \theta$};
\draw [ultra thick] (1,-0.5) node[below]{Bus 1} -- (1,0.5);
\draw [ultra thick] (7,-0.5) node[below]{Bus 2} -- (7,0.5);

% connect the lines
\draw [line] (v1) to (bus1); 
\draw [line] (bus1) to (xformer1);
\draw [line] (xformer1) to (y1);
\draw [line] (y1) to (bus2);
\draw [arrow] (bus2) to (load1);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

I attempted to create a simple MWE pasted above,
[image]

However, there are things I don't fully understand how to create or do better/less hacky, listed as below:

1. **How to draw that particular transformer symbol**, which I don't see on CircuiTikZ, and had to use `oosourcetransshape` instead. In addition, I used `oosourcetransshape` (which is a node object) rather than `oosourcetrans` (which is a path-style object) so that I can adjust its position and the `semithick` option without relying on the default line it creates. However, doing so results in the tiny whitespace at each end.
2. Is my way of adding the labels and annotations too wack? If so please teach me a better way to do the labelling.
3. Is there a less hacky way of drawing the black bus bars? If possible as a node type object (not sure if this is the correct language) like the rest of the components.

The voltage source symbol defintion comes from this post ["rotationally correct" AC source symbol in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/rotationally-correct-ac-source-symbol-in-tikz).

Thanks very much for any help in advance!!

Comment: Hi! I have no time now, but judging from your preamble you are mixing circuitikz with the internal circuits library, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how I would do it in `circuitikz` (see footnote):

1. the bus thing is used a couple of times, so I would define an on-line macro to position one. I have heavily commented it in the code.
2. The sinusoidal source is `vsourcesinshape`, you can find it there. We rotate it (beware that the anchors will rotate too, so `.s` is at the right now)
   [image]
3. The same can be done for the double-inductance simbol; use the node shape and the corresponding anchors:
   [image]

So basically it becomes quite simple:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\bushere}[2]{%
    % starting point; draw an edge and then two nodes
    % save the position
    coordinate(tmp)
    % go up and do an edge down
    ++(0,1) node[above]{#1} edge[ultra thick] ++(0,-2)
    % edges do not move the current point, go down to position the node
    ++(0,-2) node[below]{#2}
    % go back to where we started
    (tmp)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]% default line thickness
    \draw (0,0) node[vsourcesinshape, rotate=90](S){} (S.south) -- ++(1,0)
        \bushere{$\upsilon_1 = 1\angle0$}{Bus 1} -- ++(1,0)
        node[americaninductorshape, anchor=midtap, rotate=-90](L1){}
        ++(0.5,0)
        node[americaninductorshape, rotate=90](L2){} (L2.midtap)
        to[generic, l_={$y=g-\mathbf{j}b$}] ++(3,0)
        \bushere{$\upsilon_2 = V_{2}\angle\theta$}{Bus 2} -- ++(1,0)
        edge[-Stealth] ++(0.5,0)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*footnote:*

I think that the `oosourcetrans` is the correct symbol for this kind of schematics; the other one is really a symbol used in more detailed schematics with all the connections. That makes the code more straightforward:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[semithick]% default line width
    \draw (0,0) node[vsourcesinshape, rotate=90](S){} (S.south) -- ++(1,0)
        \bushere{$\upsilon_1 = 1\angle0$}{Bus 1} -- ++(1,0)
        to[oosourcetrans] ++(1,0)
        to[generic, l_={$y=g-\mathbf{j}b$}] ++(3,0)
        \bushere{$\upsilon_2 = V_{2}\angle\theta$}{Bus 2} -- ++(1,0)
        edge[-Stealth] ++(0.5,0)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer!!