# Fuse symbol with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I am using the `circuits.ee.IEC` library. However, I cannot find any fuse symbol like this:

[image: fuse symbol]

How can I define such a symbol using `circuit declare symbol`? It should be just combining the resistor symbol and a line in some way, but I don't understand the syntax well enough to do this.

Comment: You can greatly simplify and use the answer in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/).

Comment: @percusse Could you point out, how to do this, for resistor there is no `IEC/before background` path...

Comment: @percusse: A tip: If you copy-and-paste the entire link of a question you want to link to, e.g. `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library`, it'll automatically be shortened _and_ people will see the question title as a hover-tooltip, which is more helpful than a "this question": http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library

Comment: @doncherry I thought it is less disruptive but apparently the hovering is a nice functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A different approach would be to append code after the `resistor` node, similar to the `light emitting` and `direction info` styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    fuse graphic/.style={
        append after command={% At the end of the \draw command, do the following
            \bgroup % Start a new group
                [current point is local=true, % Do not influence the current point on the path
                every fuse/.try, % If `every fuse` has been defined, use it
                #1] % Apply options supplied by user
                (\tikzlastnode.west) edge [line to] (\tikzlastnode.east) % An edge, i.e. an independent path, from the west to the east of the resistor node
            \egroup% End the group
        }
    },
    fuse/.style={resistor={fuse graphic=#1}} % The fuse is just a resistor node with the `fuse graphics` key
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,0) to [fuse] (2,0)  to [fuse] (0,-2) to [fuse] (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Perhaps it would be nice to add some comments to your code to make it easier to adapt it to other examples for people who doesn't have a very deep knowledge of pgf/tikz.

Comment: @user4011: Done

Answer (score 7):

You can use annotations as described in the TikZ/PGF manual in *Section 29.2.5  Declaring and Using Annotations* to add the horizontal line over the symbol:

> Annotations are quite similar to info labels. The main difference is that they generally cause something to be drawn by default rather than some text to be added (although an annotation might also add some text).

Here is an example of `resistor` and the `fuse` that you want:

[image]

### Notes:

- This is my first attempt with annotations, and I am not sure about the coordinates used in the `edge` operation below. As per the comment by @GonzaloMedina, I have tweaked the coordinates by `(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)` to adjust for the width of the rule. However, this still seems a bit of hack and feel that there should be a better way.
- The `transform shape` option is what makes the `fuse` *points along* the path.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{circuit declare annotation=
    {HorizontalAnnotation}
    {0pt}
    {edge[to path={[-]
            ($(-0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$) 
        --  ($( 0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$)}] ()}
}

\tikzset{circuit declare symbol=fuse, 
    set fuse graphic={
        draw,
        circuit symbol size=width 4 height 1, 
        HorizontalAnnotation
    }, 
    transform shape}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,1.0) to [resistor] (3,1.0) node [right] {resistor};
    \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse]     (3,0.5) node [right] {fuse};
    \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse] (0,-2) to [fuse] (3,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to take into account the width of the rule, so using something like `($(-0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.4pt)$)
        -- ($(0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.4pt)$)}] ()}` would be better (of course, loading the `calc` library).

Comment: Or using `-\pgflinewidth` instead of `-0.4pt` above.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks. Had to use exactly half the value you suggested to get this to work.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, however It doesn't work for me if I draw a vertical path, see my edit above.

Comment: @user4011: See updated solution. Adding the `transform shape` allows the node to point along the path.

Comment: Great, thanks. I will delete my edit about your first version...