# Fuse symbol with TikZ in circuitikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

This is my standard environment for tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,positioning,fit,petri,backgrounds,shapes,arrows,through,calc,decorations.text,decorations.markings,intersections,fpu,circuits.ee.IEC,babel}
%Einstellungen von siunitx nach pgf übertragen
\SendSettingsToPgf

%%package ciruitikz is based on TikZ
\usepackage[straightvoltages,%uses arrows to define voltages, and and uses straight voltage arrows
  european,%equivalent to europeancurrents, europeanvoltages, europeanresistors, europeaninductors, europeanports, europeangfsurgearrester
  emptydiode,%the various diodes are drawn but not filled by default, i.e. when using styles such as D, sD, …Other diode styles can always be forced with e.g. Do, D-, …
  RPvoltages,%(meaning Rising Potential voltages): the arrow is in direction of rising potential, like in oldvoltagedirection, but batteries and current sources are fixed to follow the passive/active standard
  betterproportions,%nicer proportions of transistors in comparision to resistors;
  compatibility%makes it possibile to load CircuiTikZ and TikZ circuit library together
]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{circuit declare annotation={HorizontalAnnotation}{0pt}{edge[to path={[-]
    ($(-0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$) --  
    ($( 0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$)}] ()}
}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol=fuse, set fuse graphic={
    draw, circuit symbol size=width 4 height 1, HorizontalAnnotation}, 
    transform shape
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        \draw (0,1.0) to [resistor] (3,1.0) node [right] {resistor};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse]     (3,0.5) node [right] {fuse};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse] (0,-2) to [fuse] (3,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I learned from [Fuse symbol with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36271/fuse-symbol-with-tikz)
that I have to add this code in my document head to draw a fuse:

```
\tikzset{circuit declare annotation={HorizontalAnnotation}{0pt}{edge[to path={[-]
    ($(-0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$) --  
    ($( 0.5,-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$)}] ()}
}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol=fuse, set fuse graphic={
    draw, circuit symbol size=width 4 height 1, HorizontalAnnotation}, 
    transform shape
}
```

So far so good. But I need the symbol "fuse" in my normal tikzpicture enviroment, in other words I want to compile this body:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,1.0) to [resistor] (3,1.0) node [right] {resistor};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse]     (3,0.5) node [right] {fuse};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse] (0,-2) to [fuse] (3,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I change "\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]" to "\begin{tikzpicture}", because my normal environment is the package "circuitikz".
How to draw my fuse in my environment without [circuit ee IEC]?

Comment: If you use `compatibility` (which is not advised, though) you have to prepend a `*` to the path-style component of `circuitikz`.

Comment: I created an sfuse component a few years ago, if you are interested (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm).

Comment: I still have an understanding problem:
With my preferences I have the symbols from circuitikz when using the stared version (* fuse).The definition of the new symbol with \ tikzset {..} affects the standard version, right?
Why should I then use the stared version? I already know that I am using the existing symbol in circuitikz with the stared version (see the answer below), but how would I have access to the symbol defined by \ tikzset {..} in my environment without [circuit ee IEC]?

Comment: The symbols in the standard Ti*k*Z circuit library and the ones you define with `circuit declare symbols` are activated by the "circuit ee IEC" and are *completely independent*   to the `circuitikz` ones. The `compatibility` key add a `*` in front of the `to`-style form of `circuitikz` component to avoid (most) clashed between the two. `circuititz` never looks at the `circuit ee IEC` keys. My personal advice is to choose one of the two and stick to it...

Comment: @JohnKormylo, would you mind if I add your nice `sfuse` to `circuitikz`?

Comment: @Rmano - Why would I mind?  It's not like I'm selling the things.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks - I think it's better to ask when using ideas from somebody else. I will attribute you of course.

Answer (score 2):

`circuitikz` offers its own `fuse`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,positioning,fit,petri,backgrounds,shapes,arrows,through,calc,decorations.text,decorations.markings,intersections,fpu,circuits.ee.IEC,babel}
%Einstellungen von siunitx nach pgf übertragen
%\SendSettingsToPgf

%%package ciruitikz is based on TikZ
\usepackage[straightvoltages,%uses arrows to define voltages, and and uses straight voltage arrows
  european,%equivalent to europeancurrents, europeanvoltages, europeanresistors, europeaninductors, europeanports, europeangfsurgearrester
  emptydiode,%the various diodes are drawn but not filled by default, i.e. when using styles such as D, sD, …Other diode styles can always be forced with e.g. Do, D-, …
  RPvoltages,%(meaning Rising Potential voltages): the arrow is in direction of rising potential, like in oldvoltagedirection, but batteries and current sources are fixed to follow the passive/active standard
  betterproportions,%nicer proportions of transistors in comparision to resistors;
%  compatibility%makes it possibile to load CircuiTikZ and TikZ circuit library together
]
{circuitikz}



\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,1.0) to [resistor] (3,1.0) node [right] {resistor};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse]     (3,0.5) node [right] {fuse};
        \draw (0,0.5) to [fuse] (0,-2) to [fuse] (3,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, only the US version of the fuse is shown in the documentation for ciruitikz. When I looked through the documentation, that made me not even try it out. Due to my European setup, however, it becomes the correct symbol. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Michael.H ...I think there is just one version of the fuse in `circuitikz` (with variant `fuse` and `afuse`, current manual page 62. Can you please point me out to some standard/hint of which other version should be implemented? If you open an issue at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues I will look into it.

Comment: @Michael.H ah, drats! https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/487 — will try to fix it as soon as possible