# What are some packages to draw amplifiers,transistors, and circuits?

Tags: circuits

I was wondering if there exist packages that provide or support drawing circuits such as transistors, MOSFETS, and several electronic figures.

Comment: Please look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/ac-source-symbol-in-tikz-circuits-ee-iec-library)

Comment: [One more](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/area/electrical-engineering/)

Comment: The `circuitikz` package https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There's also the `pstricks` module `pst-circ`.

Comment: There is also the M4 package (https://ctan.org/pkg/circuit-macros?lang=en) but I wouldn't seriously consider using it.