# electronics TeX

Tags: symbols, diagrams

is there a good TeX flavor for expressing electronics symbols in documents?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Electric circuits in TeX, LaTeX, and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/electric-circuits-in-tex-latex-and-friends)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to draw complete circuit diagrams, you can use [`circuitikz`](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/circuitikz.html). Some examples can be found on [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuitikz/).

Answer (score 7):

My colleague Dr. Kimmo Silvonen and I decided to open source the circuit diagram macros we use for preparing our lecture material. Feel free to use it, give feedback and add new symbols:

http://code.google.com/p/latex-circuit-diagram/

There are other good packages (circuitikz is my personal favourite), but these macros are easy to use and require neither extra packages nor knowledge about PGF/TikZ.

Comment: Nice! Could you perhaps add a short example of its use (a simple circuit, for example)?

Comment: It looks interesting and handy, nice work.

Answer (score 6):

run `texdoc pst-circ` for the documentation