# Drawing vectorized digital logic circuits

Tags: circuitikz

I'm looking for a tool to draw vectorized digital logical circuits. I first wanted to use Circuitikz, but found out that their are only two input lines for AND and OR gates. Are there any options to use a LaTeX package where gates have more input lines. Or are there some usefull tools that can produce vectorized pdf files. I need these tools for a course I'm writing about digital electronics and processors.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/electric-circuits-in-tex-latex-and-friends ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example for the TikZ logic gates with four inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
  \node[and gate, inputs={normal,inverted,normal,inverted}] (A) {};
  \draw (A.input 1 -| -1,0) -- (A.input 1)
        (A.input 2 -| -1,0) -- (A.input 2)
        (A.input 3 -| -1,0) -- (A.input 3)
        (A.input 4 -| -1,0) -- (A.input 4)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: logicgate]

For more information, see PGF/TikZ 2.10 manual, section 29.3