# 3-input logic gate on circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, logic

How can I draw a 3-input logic gate with circuitikz? Is there a way to do so?

For example,

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
  (0,0) node[and port](myand){}
  (myand.in 1) node[left]{A}
  (myand.in 2) node[left]{B}
  (myand.in 3) node[left]{C}
  (myand.out) node[right]{Y}
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: I don't know about circuitikz, but with tikz you could see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13668/1410). Who knows, maybe it even helps with circuitikz.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. But it's because I use circuitikz to draw my circuits, so I'm used to it. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[minimum height=0.75cm] 
        \node[or gate US, draw,logic gate inputs=nnn] (A) {}; 
        \foreach \a in {1,...,3}
            \draw (A.input \a -| -1,0) -- (A.input \a); 
        \draw (A.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]A.output);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[minimum height=0.75cm] 
        \node[and gate US, draw,logic gate inputs=nnn] (A) {}; 
        \foreach \a in {1,...,3}
            \draw (A.input \a -| -1,0) -- (A.input \a); 
        \draw (A.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]A.output);
    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

By slight modification of this code you can acheive gates with more inputs (modifying `inputs=nnn` and `\foreach \a in {1,...,3}`).

For more, check *TikZ & PGF manual section 29.3 Page 300*

Comment: I was trying to do it with circuitikz, but it seems there's no way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Pouya, this is not working with `american nor port`.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done!!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{everyshi-2001-05-15}
%\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}%[circuit logic US]
        \draw (0,0) node[xor port ,scale=2, number inputs=3](XOR1){}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even scale only the width of the port if you dont want it to take up half your page by using yscale:

```
\draw (0,0) node[nor port ,yscale=2, number inputs=3](nor_1){}
```

Comment: you probably mean "scale only  *height* of the port".

Comment: Depends how you see it, hehe.
On your screen it would be the height, yes, but the width of the input is widened with yscale.

Comment: well, with `yscale` you scale "height", but as you say ... ;-)