# multiple inputs for logic gates

Tags: circuitikz

In the [manual](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) , section `5.1.1 Logical ports`

> All logical ports, except not, have two inputs and one output.

It seems the inputs are limited to two. All solutions I've found are using `or gate US` rather than `american nor port` which the command in the new update. In my case, I need to add three inputs to my following case,

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        block/.style={fill=blue!20,draw=red!70,thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=3.5cm}
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (0,0)
  node[block] (P1) {block} 
  ($(P1.north)$) coordinate (P1n)
  ($(P1.south)$) coordinate (P1s)
  ($(P1.east)$)  coordinate (P1e)
  (P1n) to[short,-o] ++(0, .2) coordinate (p1n) node[left] {$p1$}
  (P1s) to[short,-o] ++(0,-.2) coordinate (p1s) node[left] {$p2$}
  (P1e) to[short,-o] ++(0,0) coordinate (p1e) node[left]   {$p3$}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  (P1) ++(4,0)  node[american nor port] (And1) {}
  (p1n) -|  (And1.in 1) (p1s) -| (And1.in 2); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94607/3-input-logic-gate-on-circuitikz, maybe will be of help

Comment: There is also (And1.west).  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/three-or-more-leg-xor-gate-for-tikz/156859#156859

Comment: As I said, the solutions are not working with `american nor port`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  Some of the anchor points for this component are in odd locations.

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        block/.style={fill=blue!20,draw=red!70,thick,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=3.5cm}
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (0,0)
  node[block] (P1) {block} 
  ($(P1.north)$) coordinate (P1n)
  ($(P1.south)$) coordinate (P1s)
  ($(P1.east)$)  coordinate (P1e)
  (P1n) to[short,-o] ++(0, .2) coordinate (p1n) node[left] {$p1$}
  (P1s) to[short,-o] ++(0,-.2) coordinate (p1s) node[left] {$p2$}
  (P1e) to[short,-o] ++(0,0) coordinate (p1e) node[left]   {$p3$}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  (P1) ++(4,0)  node[american nor port] (And1) {}
  (p1n) -|  (And1.in 1) (p1s) -| (And1.in 2)
  (P1e) -- ($(And1.west)!0.33!(And1.east)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]